# Canvas.scale() does not work inside a for loop

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, scale

I made a simple program to ask this question. I want to scale by steps inside a "for" loop the drawings inside the Canvas. But, Canvas.scale() doesn't work inside a for loop. The exp_scal variable I created it to be sure not to generate very large values. Because every time Canvas.scale() would be executed inside the for loop it is raised to the power "n" (1+self.scale)^n. My question is: Why doesn't Canvas.scale() work inside the "for" loop?

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

class Win():
    def __init__(self):
        self.wind=tk.Tk()
        self.canv=tk.Canvas()
        self.canv.bind("<Button-1>", self.magnify)
        self.canv.pack()
        self.scal=1
        self.exp_scal=0
        self.draw()
        self.wind.mainloop()
        
    def draw(self):
        self.canv.create_text(220,50,text="left click anywhere to test")
        self.canv.create_oval(10,10,90,90,outline="black")
        
    def magnify(self,e):
        self.exp_scal=self.scal
        for i in range(10,20):
            print("magnify() is running")
            time.sleep(0.25)
            self.scal=1+i/1000
            self.exp_scal = self.exp_scal * self.scal
            print("scal      : " , self.scal)
            print("exp_scal  : " , self.exp_scal)
            self.canv.scale("all",0,0,self.scal,self.scal) # <-- Why doesn't this do anything? 
        self.canv.scale("all",0,0,self.exp_scal,self.exp_scal)

def main():
    win=Win()

main()
```

Comment: There are lots of questions relating to `sleep` and `after`.  Try searching for an answer in those.

Comment: @TlsChris How will that help here? Also, for OP's benefit, using `sleep` in a tkinter app is best avoided - that's what `after` is for anyway

Comment: Does this help? I put outside of for looping self.canv.scale("all",0,0,self.scal,self.scal) 
        #self.canv.scale("all",0,0,self.exp_scal,self.exp_scal)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `after` instead of `time`. Replace your `magnify` method with the following code.

```py
    def magnifier(self, i):
        self.scal=1+i/1000
        self.exp_scal = self.exp_scal * self.scal

        print("scal      : " , self.scal)
        print("exp_scal  : " , self.exp_scal)

        self.canv.scale("all",0,0,self.scal,self.scal)
        i = i + 1
        if i < 20:
            self.wind.after(250, self.magnifier, i)
        else:
            self.canv.scale("all",0,0,self.exp_scal,self.exp_scal)
        
    def magnify(self,e):
        self.exp_scal=self.scal
        print("magnify() is running")
        self.wind.after(0, self.magnifier, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Canvas.scale()` is not working because changes are not reflected immediately, when you call `canvas.scale()` changes are only recorded in event loop of `Tkinter` and will be executed when event loop executes.
In your code for loop is running without waiting for the event loop to execute, so the changes can't be seen, in this case you can fix this in two ways as I think;

1- Using `after()` instead of `time.sleep()` as described by @Derek

2- Forcing the event loop to make changes immediately after scaling the canvas, code given below;

```
def magnify(self,e):
        self.exp_scal=self.scal
        for i in range(10,20):
            print("magnify() is running")
            time.sleep(0.25)
            self.scal=1+i/1000
            self.exp_scal = self.exp_scal * self.scal
            print("scal      : " , self.scal)
            print("exp_scal  : " , self.exp_scal)
            self.canv.scale("all",0,0,self.scal,self.scal)
            self.canv.update() # force the event loop to execute 
         self.canv.scale("all",0,0,self.exp_scal,self.exp_scal)
```